# MPI_Gatherv doesn't work correctly

Tags: c, mpi

I write code that do multiplying a Vector by a Matrix. I use the MPI. The matrix is distributed of chunks which consist of rows. The chunks size not always be equal maybe. The chunks are worked correct, but when i try to run this i get half empty vector. However, I was expected to receive a full vector. Please look at the attached code. I think the problem is in the MPI_Gatherv function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define COLUMN 4
#define ROW 7
#define  dp 100.0f

// Local start
#define chunk_low(commrank, commsize, nvert) \
    ((commrank) * (nvert) / (commsize))

// Local end
#define chunk_height(commrank, commsize, nvert) \
    (chunk_low((commrank) + 1, commsize, nvert) - 1)

// Local size
#define chunk_size(commrank, commsize, nvert) \
    (chunk_height(commrank, commsize, nvert) - \
    chunk_low(commrank, commsize, nvert) + 1)

// Matrix initialization function
void init_matrix(int column, int row, float *matrix)
{
    int j, i;
    printf("\nMatrix\n");
    for(i=0; i < row; i++){
        for(j=0; j < column; j++){
            matrix[i*column+j] = i * column + j; // (float)rand()/RAND_MAX * dp *2.0f - dp;
            printf(" %f ", matrix[i * column + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rank, size;
    int i, j;
    float *vm, *local_matrix, *result, *vector;
    double time1, time2;
    int *displs, *rcounts, *scounts;

    vm = (float *)calloc(ROW * COLUMN, sizeof(float));
    vector = malloc(COLUMN * sizeof(float));
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    /* Process 0 - master  */
    if (rank==0)
    {

        printf("\nNumbers of proccesses %d. \nElements in vector %d.\n", size, COLUMN);

        /* Init vector vA  */
        init_matrix(COLUMN, ROW, vm);

        for (i = 0; i < COLUMN; i++) {
            vector[i] = (11 * 5) + (11 * i);
        }

        result = (float *)calloc(ROW, sizeof(float));

        //Time begining calculating of programm
        time1=MPI_Wtime();

    }
    /* End of work process 0  */

    displs = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    scounts = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    rcounts = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        displs[i] = chunk_low(i, size, ROW) * COLUMN; // Position initialization
        rcounts[i] = scounts[i] = chunk_size(i, size, ROW) * COLUMN;
    }

    local_matrix  = (float *)calloc(chunk_size(rank, size, ROW) * COLUMN, sizeof(float));

    MPI_Bcast(vector, COLUMN, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Scatterv(vm, scounts, displs, MPI_FLOAT, local_matrix,
                 rcounts[rank], MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int local_row = scounts[rank] / COLUMN;
    float *local_result = (float *)calloc(local_row, sizeof(float));;

    for(i = 0; i < local_row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++) {
            local_result[i] += local_matrix[i * COLUMN + j] * vector[j];
        }
    }

    MPI_Gatherv(local_result, local_row, MPI_FLOAT, result, rcounts, displs, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    /* Only master-process  */
    if (rank==0)
    {
        //Time ending programm
        time2=MPI_Wtime();
        printf("\nTime parallel calculation = %f s.\n",time2-time1);
        for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
        {
            printf(" %f\n", result[i]);
        }
    }
    // End work of master-process

    /* Delete storage arrays of process */
    free(displs);
    free(scounts);
    free(rcounts);
    free(local_matrix);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

After run this code i was expected:
 484.000000
 1628.000000
 2772.000000
 3916.000000
 5060.000000
 6204.000000
 7348.000000

But get this result:
 484.000000
 1628.000000
 0.000000
 0.000000
 0.000000
 0.000000
 0.000000

Answer (score 0):

The problem was articulated in the displs, which we passed to MPI_Gatherv